# Firebase FCM get tokens for old iOS APNS tokens

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

With the change of GCM to FCM through Google, we are looking to bring our push notifications for iOS into FCM as well. Without providing an update, which would register each user to the Firebase push service, is it possible to subscribe all current users tokens to the firebase service, therefore generating FCM keys for them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [batchImport](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#create_registration_tokens_for_apns_tokens) method of the InstanceID API to import a list of APNs tokens which will return a mapping of InstanceID tokens that you can then use to send messages to iOS app instances using FCM.

Comment: I noticed this is for GCM, do these transfer directly to FCM?

Comment: This is an instance id API so it will apply to both GCM and FCM.

Comment: What happens if I don't update the app with Firebase and it uses old APNs. Will the updated InstanceID be able to send a notification to the old APN device? @ArthurThompson

Comment: @MukulMore yes, by importing the existing APNs tokens you will map new Instance ID tokens to them. Sending to those new Instance ID tokens will result in devices with corresponding (old) APNs tokens receiving the messages.

Comment: Ay way to do the conversion offline without calling a web API?