# Firebase Importing existing Batch token for Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

From the documentation of Firebase there's iOS [importing batch of token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37464706/firebase-fcm-get-tokens-for-old-ios-apns-tokens) how to do it in Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [migration guide from Parse to Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/parse-android#firebase-notifications).

There is no way to import old Android tokens. You will have to update your app so that it uses InstanceID tokens, which FCM requires.

Comment: then my existing android parse token (1m users) would be useless as I created new instance token..? because those token is not supported with firebase..?

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to import tokens anywhere. Because you use the same Google project for Firebase, it does not require any token migration or whatever.

Comment: My token is from Parse and to be migrated to Firebase, so there will be no issues for my tokens as I placed it to my FCM Server?

Comment: @avinadoid You should mention that detail on your post.

Comment: You don't need to import tokens. You can register the client by receiving the fcm token when the app updates.