# The registration token is not a valid FCM registration token

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, passkit

I'm trying to send a message to my device using a token I've gotten from a ticket saved in my PassWallet app in my Android device.

The device sends all the information required to update a pass using apple's wallet spec. However, I'm using FCM to send the notification and I'm getting this error: "The registration token is not a valid FCM registration token"

```
{
errorInfo: 
   { code: 'messaging/invalid-argument',
     message: 'The registration token is not a valid FCM registration token' },
  codePrefix: 'messaging' 
}
```

The code I'm using to send the message is the one from the Admin SDK sample:

```
var message = {
        token: device.pushToken
      };

      admin.messaging().send(message)
        .then((response) => {
          console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log('Error sending message:', error);
        });
```

- I'm not sure if my message is incomplete and I need something else in
  the body.
- If the token expired (Where you can verify this on Firebase).
- If the message needs to specify whether is Android, iOS(APNS), etc...

This is the full stack trace:

```
Error: The registration token is not a valid FCM registration token
    at FirebaseMessagingError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/srv/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:39:28)
    at FirebaseMessagingError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (/srv/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:85:28)
    at new FirebaseMessagingError (/srv/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:241:16)
    at Function.FirebaseMessagingError.fromServerError (/srv/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:271:16)
    at FirebaseMessagingRequestHandler.handleHttpError (/srv/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging-api-request.js:125:50)
    at /srv/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging-api-request.js:113:23
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
  errorInfo: 
   { code: 'messaging/invalid-argument',
     message: 'The registration token is not a valid FCM registration token' },
  codePrefix: 'messaging' }
```

Comment: I don't think PassWallet tokens are valid FCM tokens. To get a valid FCM token, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#access_the_registration_token

Comment: Hi Frank, I'm not sure if what you are suggesting is send a message using apns or only generate new ones. The thing is passwallet is an app that I don't control but they use .pkpass files as in iOS wallet, is it possible for me to send notifications to this app through apn.

Comment: To send messages through FCM you need an FCM token. And whatever you get from passwallet doesn't seem to be a valid FCM token.

Comment: Frank you are right about the token being the problem. I tried to send a message through postman and curl and I'm getting this error in the response: "error": "InvalidRegistration". And it's when I use the pushToken returned by the pkpass file to send the notification to that device. What I'm not sure is how to make that token a valid token for FCM or if I should use APNS instead

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, based on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37464706/firebase-fcm-get-tokens-for-old-ios-apns-tokens. I think that what I need to do is convert the APN token into a FCM token, but the batchImport requires an application and says is the app Bundle. The thing is I want the tokens to work no matter of the wallet app the user has in their phone. What should I do in this case? I'm getting this response "message_id": "0:1547059178561977%9ba8a687f9fd7ecd" from a fake application package which means I my poor knowledge that the message was sent

Comment: I'm not sure how Wallet apps work. In general I think that you need to have an app ID to be able to send a notification to that app. But I admit that my knowledge on this is quite limited, so hope somebody else at this point might know more. It could also be that you should post a new question now explaining how you're trying to convert a Wallet token to an FCM token, and showing the API you're trying to call.

Comment: Frank you were right, after converting those tokens I was able to send messages sometimes then I started receiving some other error I posted another question with more details, thanks for your help.

Comment: Hello @Dyan Im facing the same problem. How exactly did you solve the problem?
Can I contact you on skype or something?

Best regards,
Dennis

Answer (score -1):

All information about the updated pass you should send to the Passwallet server. 
Please find the latest instructions here: https://github.com/Kwiket/passwallet

Passwallet Team