# Why would push notifications stop working for iOS but not android?

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

We have a mobile app built in Angular/Ionic that all of a sudden stopped receiving push notifications on iOS, however they still work on android.

the message we get back from firebase is this:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "The registration token is not a valid FCM registration token",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.firebase.fcm.v1.FcmError",
        "errorCode": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Check these related issues: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54047803/the-registration-token-is-not-a-valid-fcm-registration-token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54047803/the-registration-token-is-not-a-valid-fcm-registration-token) [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37464706/firebase-fcm-get-tokens-for-old-ios-apns-tokens?noredirect=1&lq=1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37464706/firebase-fcm-get-tokens-for-old-ios-apns-tokens?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: how are you managing the tokens ? are you updating the token every time the app launches ? removing stale records from your server ? tokens can change over time, make sure to update them regularly. read more: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/manage-tokens